# OAuth2::Error with LinkedIn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm using Rails and OAuth so users can sign in with LinkedIn. I'm following this tutorial http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-authentication-oauth-2-0-omniauth/. 
I registered my app on LinkedIn Developers and followed the instructions to a T. However when use localhost to test the app, and I'm navigated to the LinkedIn authorize page, I get this Action Controller error message as a callback:

OAuth2::Error

> invalid_request: missing required parameters, includes an invalid
>   parameter value, parameter more than once. : Unable to retrieve access
>   token : appId or redirect uri does not match authorization code or
>   authorization code expired {"error_description":"missing required
>   parameters, includes an invalid parameter value, parameter more than
>   once. : Unable to retrieve access token : appId or redirect uri does
>   not match authorization code or authorization code
>   expired","error":"invalid_request"}

What can I do to resolve this, so OAuth with LinkedIn works?[Here is my code in omniauth.rb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQIg4.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can not set localhost directly as your callback. You can use 127.0.0.1:3000 instead of localhost to get it working.